# Foreach loop, only 5 items are displayed

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have a foreach loop, I have an array containing the data but only 5 data are 
fetched, I'm new to PHP so I'm kinda confused. I have more than 5 data and I want them to be all displayed.

CODE:

```
$args = array(
    'type' => 'post',
    'child_of' => $catName,
    'parent' => get_query_var(''),
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'hierarchical' => 1,
    'exclude' => '',
    'include' => '',
    'number' => '5',
    'taxonomy' => 'category',
    'pad_counts' => true 
);

$categories = get_categories($args);
foreach($categories as $category) {
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have an array containing the data but only 5 data are fetched

That's because of the `number` argument, `'number' => '5'`. Simply change this to `'number' => ''`